# Fetching and displaying the provisioning status of a phone number

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, json, flask

I have the following function:

```
def dnd_return(number,my_timeout):
    try:
        r =requests.get("https://dndcheck.p.mashape.com/index.php?mobilenos= {}".format(number), timeout =my_timeout)
    except (requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as err:
        return "Error fetching DND info"
    else:
        return r.text
```

Then I have the following route:

```
@app.route('/track_mobile_numbers', methods=['POST','GET'])
def mobile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get("number", "") != "":
            number = request.form['number']
            number = number.replace(" ","")
            number = number.replace('+91', '')
            number = number.strip()
            strnumber = number
            dnd_list = []
            if len(number) == 10:
                try:
                    dnd_dump = dnd_return(number,9)
                    json_dump = json.loads(dnd_dump)
                    j = json_dump[0]

                    if j['DND_status'] != "deactivated" and j['DND_status'] != "off":
                        dnd_list.append("DND status : "+j['DND_status'])
                        dnd_list.append("Date of Activation : "+j['activation_date'])
                        dnd_list.append("Preference : "+j['current_preference'])

                    else:
                        dnd_list.append("DND status : "+j['DND_status'])
                except Exception as e:
                    dnd_list.append(e)
            else:
                dnd_list.append("The number should contain 10 digits")

            number = number[:4]
            try:
                number = int(number)
                num = mobileNumbers.query.filter_by(number = number).first()
                return render_template('mobilenumbers.html', 
                                        strnumber = "Mobile number : " + strnumber, 
                                        operator = "Operator : " + num.operator, 
                                        state = "State : " + num.state,
                                        dnd = dnd_list
                                      )
            except Exception as err:
                return render_template('mobilenumbers.html',
                                        error = err
                                      )
        else:
            return render_template('mobilenumbers.html',
                                    error = "Please enter a valid number"
                                  )
    else:
        return render_template('mobilenumbers.html')
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can you recommend improvements to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You may want to use a different template for error messages. You can still reuse the overall design by [inheriting](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/templateinheritance/) from a base template.
- You *replace variable values* a lot, making it hard to follow what the *meaning* of variables like `num`, `number` and `strnumber` are throughout the code. *Instead write functions* which create the various transformations of the input that you need, making your variables unchanged throughout the code. For example:

  ```
  def format_number(number):
      return number.replace(" ","").replace('+91', '').strip()
  ```

  Now you can get from `number` to `strnumber` without ever changing the former.
- In some error cases you render the template with `error` set, but in at least one you use a different error message delivery: `dnd_list.append("The number should contain 10 digits")`. This seems inconsistent.
- The various large branches of code should be moved into separate functions.
- Single letter variables like `e`, `r` and `j` make this code hard to maintain. Yes, it's kinda obvious from context, but the less context you have to keep in your head while developing, the better.

Comment: I'm unable to understand your second point. Can you give me an example on how I can use functions for the transformations? Thanks!